# How read csv files with comma (,) as separators in R

Tags: r, import-from-csv

I'm trying to read this csv file in R. (scores.csv)

```
ALVO,P,Prediction,fold
1,0.9079557994069131,"1",0
1,0.4323657303144317,"0",0
1,0.9944246408740756,"1",0
1,0.8025072441292207,"1",0
1,0.8687043760021418,"1",0
1,0.8728815023271057,"1",0
1,0.9998157504312343,"1",0
1,0.6610699528239422,"1",0
1,0.9994385364719802,"1",0
```

I've tried this:

> result <- read.csv("C:/scores.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"")

**AND**
THIS:

> result <- read.csv("C:/scores.csv")

It's not working, I'm getting the P,Prediction,fold with NA values

> head(result)

**but I got this:**

```
                        ALVO  P Prediction fold
1 1,0.9079557994069131,"1",0 NA         NA   NA
2 1,0.4323657303144317,"0",0 NA         NA   NA
3 1,0.9944246408740756,"1",0 NA         NA   NA
4 1,0.8025072441292207,"1",0 NA         NA   NA
5 1,0.8687043760021418,"1",0 NA         NA   NA
6 1,0.8728815023271057,"1",0 NA         NA   NA
```

Someone already have done that?

please help!

Comment: Simple read.csv with just the file name reads it fine. Is that not what you want?

Comment: I already tried that, but I getting the P, Prediction and fold columns ans NA it's not separating the variables between commas @user3949008

Comment: It may be that there is more to this data and an error somewhere else in the file. Your sample input is being read properly in my console. Perhaps restarting your R console and trying is worth it?

Comment: @user3949008 it worked !! Do you know why this kind of sh*t happens?

Comment: Hard to say (for me), but some memory problems or such things may be. It happens rarely though. I also waste some time when it happens, but when something obvious is not working, I do restart and try again.

Comment: @AlvaroJoao _"Do you know why"_ : yep. Windows.

Comment: you nailed, I'm using a pc from work... windows @hrbrmstr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix cat output is below:

```
> cat input.csv 
ALVO,P,Prediction,fold
1,0.9079557994069131,"1",0
1,0.4323657303144317,"0",0
1,0.9944246408740756,"1",0
1,0.8025072441292207,"1",0
1,0.8687043760021418,"1",0
1,0.8728815023271057,"1",0
1,0.9998157504312343,"1",0
1,0.6610699528239422,"1",0
1,0.9994385364719802,"1",0
```

R output is below:

```
read.csv('input.csv')
  ALVO         P Prediction fold
1    1 0.9079558          1    0
2    1 0.4323657          0    0
3    1 0.9944246          1    0
4    1 0.8025072          1    0
5    1 0.8687044          1    0
6    1 0.8728815          1    0
7    1 0.9998158          1    0
8    1 0.6610700          1    0
9    1 0.9994385          1    0
```